# how can i get database password at runtime before connecting to the database

Tags: java

in my applicationcontext.xml  i have this :

```
       <bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dashboardsupervisor" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="1234" />
</bean>
```

here i am connecting with my database :

```
              ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
        "applicationContext.xml");
        MySQLRdbHelper rdbHelper = (MySQLRdbHelper)  
                    ctx.getBean("ManagerSupervisor");
```

What is want is to NOT  read the password "1234" from my applicationcontext.xml 
and read it from some properties file in my local drive .
as this will be running on different machines and every one have different passwords.

Can i achieve this .

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can, and the key to this is Springs `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`.

For example, you create a file on your file system called `database.properties`, containing your password (note, that you can also add more settings to this file, like username, JDBC url, etc).

```
jdbc.password=1234
```

Next, you need to declare a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` bean and point it to the `database.properties` file:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>path/to/database.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Note that the path is interpreted as a *classpath resource*, unless it is prefixed with `file:`.

Finally, *replace* the configuration of your `dataSource` bean: replace

```
<property name="password" value="1234" />
```

with

```
<property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
```

Comment: thanks for your help , I have changed my applicationcontext.xml now ,but its giving error , I edited my question , please have a look

Comment: i have the database.properties in my F drive with jdbc.password=1234

Comment: thanks , its saying "class path resource [F:/database.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist":: whereas database.properties file is in my F drive

Comment: In your question it says `/F:/database.properties`. It should be `F:/database.properties`, so without the leading `/`. Also, the error message reads `class path resource`, so maybe the file should reside on the classpath; I cannot find evidence of that in the documentation, though.

Comment: oh, if it needs to be in classpath , then that will not serve the purpose.: i tried chaning it to F:/database.properties, but no luck

Comment: Try specifying the location like so: `file:F:/database.properties`.

Comment: hi, looking for a small help , if i do not know the exact path of this file , database.properties,could there be a way where i can find the file if its in c:, or e:....:    Any idea, thanks

Comment: Sounds like a different question, why don't you post a new one to see if anyone can help you with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could use profiles:

```
 GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
 ctx.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("dev1");
 ctx.load("*Context.xml");
 ctx.refresh();

 <bean id="database1" profile="dev1"/>
 <bean id="database2" profile="dev2">
```

Comment: Where does the password come from in this scenario?

Comment: @mthmulders you set it in each bean, each environment gets it's own bean, thus it's own password

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you have the password hardcoded in a bean?

Comment: @mthmulders yup, you did understand perfectly. 99% of the time that is not a problem at all. Also this is a suggestion, not a "DO IT!" ;)

Comment: I'm not a big fan of putting production passwords in source control... but I'm glad to see it's not a "DO IT!" ;)

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create the data source in application server and configure as below in application.xml

```
  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
     <property name="jndiName"><value>YourDSName</value></property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>
      .....
   </bean>
```